# gdb shows that EBP contains a value other than some address(which is what it is supposed to contain). How is this possible?

Tags: binary-analysis, gdb

I am fairly new to RE and Binary Exploitation, I have learned basic assembly instructions for Binary Exploitation and I was doing [Protostar exercises (stack0)](https://exploit.education/protostar/stack-zero/) in which I have to simply overflow the `buffer` variable. Disassembly of main function is:-

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x080483f4 <main+0>:    push   ebp
0x080483f5 <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x080483f7 <main+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x080483fa <main+6>:    sub    esp,0x60
0x080483fd <main+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c],0x0
0x08048405 <main+17>:   lea    eax,[esp+0x1c]
0x08048409 <main+21>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x0804840c <main+24>:   call   0x804830c <gets@plt>
0x08048411 <main+29>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c]
0x08048415 <main+33>:   test   eax,eax
0x08048417 <main+35>:   je     0x8048427 <main+51>
0x08048419 <main+37>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048500
0x08048420 <main+44>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048425 <main+49>:   jmp    0x8048433 <main+63>
0x08048427 <main+51>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048529
0x0804842e <main+58>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048433 <main+63>:   leave  
0x08048434 <main+64>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I set a break point on `ret` instruction and run the program but when I examine the stack in `gdb`, it shows this output(overflow after 90 A's):

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x29 41
ecx            0xb7fd84c0   -1208122176
edx            0xb7fd9340   -1208118464
ebx            0xb7fd7ff4   -1208123404
esp            0xbffff7bc   0xbffff7bc
ebp            0x41414141   0x41414141
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x8048434    0x8048434 <main+64>
eflags         0x200246 [ PF ZF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

When looking at `ebp` I am really curious to know that what happened that caused `ebp` to have value `0x41414141`? What I understand is when `leave` isntruction is executed stack frame is destroyed and `x/x $esp is 0x41414141` which makes sense and `x/x $ebp is Cannot access memory at address 0x41414141`
so how does value of `ebp` changed to `0x41414141`?

PS: I already solved that exercise but while examining the stack I was not getting how `ebp` got changed and feel free to edit the question tag because I am not sure what tag will be appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `leave` instruction is equivalent to:

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

The second instruction pops the value on the top of the stack and stores it in `ebp`. In the case of a stack-based buffer overflow, your stack layout looks like:

```
<--- low addresses           high addresses --->
[ buffer being overflowed ][saved EBP][RET ADDR]
                           ^
```

When `leave` is executed, the `mov esp, ebp` instruction first restores `esp` to point at the marked location in the diagram above, then pops a value off the stack into `ebp`. So if you've overflowed the buffer with 'AAAA...', both the saved `ebp` and the return address will be set to `0x41414141`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but why we cannot access the memory location where `ebp` is pointing now?

Comment: Unless by coincidence `0x41414141` happens to be a memory region that the program was already using, then there's no reason to expect it to be accessible. `0x41414141` is just the "AAAA" you wrote to the stack (interpreted as a 32-bit integer).

Comment: That clarifies it, thanks for explanantion

Answer (score 2):

For the CPU, `ebp` (and even `esp` most of the time) are not really different from `eax`, `ebx` and other registers. They can contain any data, not necessarily valid addresses. You only get problems (faults/exceptions) if you actually try to execute instructions that use those registers as addresses (directly or indirectly), or, in case of `ESP`, [an interrupt happens](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts).